# Get unique id value from multiple classes with the class name on click

Tags: jquery

These rows are dynamically generated with ids based on the database. I'm basically making a program that communicates with PHP via Ajax requests, these rows are based off that request coming from a JSON format.

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td>New</td>
    <td class="tdClick" id="1">Regular Loan</td>
    <td>3/18/2020 13:42</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sagittis mauris ac felis tristique hendrerit. Cras efficitur sem elit. Morbi pharetra turpis accumsan volutpat placerat.</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td>New</td>
    <td class="tdClick" id="13">Educational Loan</td>
    <td>3/18/2020 14:42</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sagittis mauris ac felis tristique hendrerit. Cras efficitur sem elit. Morbi pharetra turpis accumsan volutpat placerat.</td>
</tr>
```

Now what I want to happen, is when I click on a td with class `tdClick`, a modal appears that sends a request to my PHP file and gets another JSON response - however I want the ID to be passed as the data in the ajax code.

Normally, if the id was static and there's only one class I'd create something like:

```
$(".tdClick").click(function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

However, I have multiple tdClick classes and each of them feature different IDs. The code above is my current code and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Try prop instead of attr.

Answer (score 0):

Since "*these rows are dynamically generated*", you can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach a single event listener to tables rows that exist now or are added in the future like:

```
// Attach a delegated event handler
$(document).on("click", ".tdClick", function(event) {
   var id = this.id;
   alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to wrap your event handler inside $(document).ready. Moreover, you can also get the `id` for each td  using `e.target.id`. `e.target`  will return the element (td in this case) for which click event occurred

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.tdClick').click(function(event)  {
alert(event.target.id);
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td>New</td>
    <td class="tdClick" id="1">Regular Loan</td>
    <td>3/18/2020 13:42</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sagittis mauris ac felis tristique hendrerit. Cras efficitur sem elit. Morbi pharetra turpis accumsan volutpat placerat.</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td>New</td>
    <td class="tdClick" id="13">Educational Loan</td>
    <td>3/18/2020 14:42</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sagittis mauris ac felis tristique hendrerit. Cras efficitur sem elit. Morbi pharetra turpis accumsan volutpat placerat.</td>
</tr>
</table>
```